# Get weekly average for work days in each week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to find weekly average from table given below (only work days - monday to friday). Number I am searching average is AVAI_NUM. I have to calculate average of AVAI_NUM for each week in given period.

Example:
If period is january 2016:

```
declare @dDateFrom date = cast('2016-01-01' as date)
declare @dDateTo date = cast('2016-01-31' as date)
```

Table looks like this:

```
declare @scavai table
(
    avai_key int,
    avai_dat date,
    avai_num int
)
```

Fill table with data:

```
insert into @scavai(avai_Key, avai_dat, avai_num)
    select 1, cast('2016-01-01' as date), 3
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-02' as date), 2
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-03' as date), 5
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-04' as date), 6
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-05' as date), 1
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-06' as date), 8
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-07' as date), 4
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-08' as date), 3
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-09' as date), 2
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-10' as date), 1
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-11' as date), 9
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-12' as date), 7
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-13' as date), 3
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-14' as date), 8
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-15' as date), 3
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-16' as date), 2
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-17' as date), 3
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-18' as date), 1
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-19' as date), 4
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-20' as date), 5
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-21' as date), 7
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-22' as date), 3
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-23' as date), 3
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-25' as date), 3
    union all
    select 1, cast('2016-01-26' as date), 3
```

I know how to calculate number of weeks in given period:

```
select DATEDIFF(ww, '2016-01-01', '2016-01-31')
```

But I don't know how to calculate AVAI_NUM for work days in each week and divide this with number of days in particular week and then summarize all of this and divide with number of weeks?

Comment: try   AVG(avai_num) over (partition by datepart(week,  avai_dat) order by avai_dat)

Comment: @nazark - can you please post this as answer? (whole query on example if possible). Thank you.

Comment: posted but not sure what result you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
select *,
    AVG(cast(avai_num as decimal)) over 
    (partition by datepart(week,  avai_dat) order by (select 1)) avg1
    from @scavai 
    where avai_dat between @dDateFrom and @dDateTo 
    order by avai_dat
```

Comment: Thanks for answers, but results are different inside day of the week. Average result should be the same for every day inside week.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. Is it possible to have decimal result for average instead of integer? AVAI_NUM is integer, but average is more accurate if it is decimal(8,2).